# Updating angularjs controller with websocket data

Tags: angularjs, websocket

I'm trying to update my angularjs controller after receiving new information from a websocket server. I am using angular-websockets to create the connection with the websocket server.

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('VotingApp', ['ngWebSocket'])
.factory('MyVotingResults', function ($websocket) {
    // Open a WebSocket connection
    var ws = $websocket('ws://localhost:80/test');        

    //defaults
    var collection = {
        Question: "This is my question?",
        Results: [
            { Percentage: 0, Picture: "http://www.kvmechelen.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/De-Witte.jpg", Player: "Seth De Witte", Number: "4", Position: "Defender", Winner: true },
            { Percentage: 0, Picture: "http://www.kvmechelen.be/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/15-16grpsf-037-19715104962_19124904603_o.jpg", Player: "Tim Matthys", Number: "7", Position: "Midfielder", Winner: false },
            { Percentage: 0, Picture: "http://www.kvmechelen.be/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/NICOLAS-VERDIER.jpg", Player: "Nicolas Verdier", Number: "99", Position: "Forward", Winner: false }
        ]
    };

    ws.onOpen(function () {
        console.log("connectie is open");
        ws.send("Hello world!");
    });

    ws.onClose(function () {
        console.log("connectie is closed");
    }); 

    ws.onError(function () {
        console.log("error!");
    });

    ws.onMessage(function (response) {
        console.log("received an update: ", response);
        collection = JSON.parse(response.data);
    });

    return {
        collection: collection,
        get: function () {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'get' }));
        }
    };
})
.controller('VotingController', function ($scope, MyVotingResults) {
    $scope.Data = MyVotingResults.collection;
})
```

I am initializing my collection variable with some data to begin. That works and it is shown on the page like it is supposed to.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="content" ng-controller="VotingController">
    <div class="vraag">
        <p>{{Data.Question}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="antwoorden">
        <div class="antw" ng-repeat="result in Data.Results">
            <div class="result">
                <div class="resultWinner">
                    <img src="img/winner.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="resultImage">
                    <img src="{{result.Picture}}" />
                </div>
                <div class="resultBalk">
                    <p><span class="timer">{{result.Percentage}}</span>%</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="antwText">
                <p><span>{{result.Number}}.</span> {{result.Player}}</p>
                <p>{{result.Position}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My websocketserver is a simple testserver that sends back this json:

```
{
"Question": "Who deserves the Man of the Match award?",
"Results": [{
    "Percentage": 25.0,
    "Picture": "http://www.kvmechelen.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/De-Witte.jpg",
    "Player": "Seth De Witte",
    "Number": "4",
    "Position": "Defender",
    "Winner": false
}, {
    "Percentage": 40.0,
    "Picture": "http://www.kvmechelen.be/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/15-16grpsf-037-19715104962_19124904603_o.jpg",
    "Player": "Tim Matthys",
    "Number": "7",
    "Position": "Midfielder",
    "Winner": true
}, {
    "Percentage": 35.0,
    "Picture": "http://www.kvmechelen.be/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/NICOLAS-VERDIER.jpg",
    "Player": "Nicolas Verdier",
    "Number": "99",
    "Position": "Forward",
    "Winner": false
}]
}
```

Why won't page update? I based my code on this example:
https://angularclass.github.io/angular-websocket/

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I changed my controller to this but it still doesn't work unfortunately.

```
.controller('VotingController', function ($scope, MyVotingResults) {
    $scope.Data = MyVotingResults.collection;

    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return MyVotingResults.collection;
    }, function (newValue) {
        $scope.Data = newValue;
    });
})
```

Comment: Once the data comes back from the socket you have to update your controller. Right now it is only making the connection but you are not updating anything just changing the value of `collection`

Comment: And how do I do this if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

You can "watch" that service variable in your controller and update the scope accordingly:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return MyVotingResults.collection;
}, function (newValue) {
    $scope.Data = newValue;
});
```

Comment: I used this piece of code but it still doesn't work :(